# Why postcss-merge-rules vesion give me an error Angular 5 - Webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4, angular-universal

**Error with postcss plugin**

This a log when I tried a ng build --prod, I' using angular universal only give me that error with bootstrap and font-awesome.

```
10% building modules 4/6 modules 2 active ...ules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.cssUnknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.17, but postcss-merge-rules uses 5.2.18. Perhaps this i 55% building modules 380/383 modules 3 active ...ules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.cssUnknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.17, but postcss-merge-rules uses 5.2.18. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.
```

Comment: Can you give more information about your configuration and the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, you should update your angular cli version to the latest beta, run this command:

at first install it globally :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.0-beta.1
```

//    then you should update your current project:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.7.0-beta.1
```

Comment: Have they said anything regarding when the next stable/non-beta release is?

Comment: @Reed, there is a release candidate v1.7.0-rc.0

Comment: @angular.cli@1.7.0 was released February 16th and I can confirm it fixes the issue! See the releases here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases