# ng build error on bootstrap min file when I use --prod

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular5

When I run the command

```
ng build
```

it seems everything is OK.

but when I run

```
ng build --prod
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `>= 1%`
    at error (/var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:37:11)
    at /var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:222:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (/var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:196:13)
    at /var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/dist/index.js:261:51
    at LazyResult.run (/var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/var/www/parseek.admin/front/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
....
```

I installed bootstrap with `npm install`. Is there anything wrong with `bootstrap.min.css` !?

Comment: It's the postcss-merge-rules that's most likely causing the problem. Angular CLI minifies all css for production anyways, so no need for a package like that. Regardless, have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713063/why-postcss-merge-rules-vesion-give-me-an-error-angular-5-webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Z.bagley commented, I upgraded my `angular cli` by the following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.7.0-beta.1
```

The problem solved.